# Menu option not showing correct output

Tags: c++, menu, output, menuitem

I am having an issue with this menu driven program for a link list class which I created.  I created an abstract class and successfully linked it to this menu driven program.  How ever I am having problems it.

First I populate the linked list successfully with option 1, however when I am done and try to choose another menu option for example to display my list, it does not display anything as if it is empty.

Can some one point me in the right direction, on how to tackle this problem with this menu driven program.

My intentions for this program

1. choose option one in order to populate my linked list class
2. I would like to return to the original menu to choose other option
   for example : delete a number from my list, or just to display my current list

   ```
   // This program demonstrates the displayList member function.
   #include <iostream>
   #include "NumberList.h"
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
      double user_input = 0;
      int menu_choice = 0;
      int num = 0;
      NumberList list;// Define a NumberList object.



      //display for the user 
      cout << "                             Your Menu Options   \n\t\t\t\t  ";

      cout << "\n\n\n 1.   This Option Will Allow You To Add Numbers To The Link Class ";

      cout << "\n\n 2.   This Option Will Allow You To Insert A Number To The Middle Of The List ";

      cout << "\n\n 3.   This Option Will Allow You To Delete A Number From The List ";

      cout << "\n\n 4.   This Option Will Allow You To View The List Created ";

      cout << "\n\n                          Your Menu Choice Is : ";
      cin >> menu_choice;

      switch ( menu_choice)
      {
         case 1:
            // Get the number of days.
            cout << "\n\n                   HOW MANY NUMBERS WILL YOU LIKE TO ENTER : ";
            cin >> num;

            // Get the sales for each day and accumulate a total.
            for (int count = 1; count <= num; count++)
            {
               double list_number;
               cout << " Please Enter Number ( " << count << " ): ";
               cin >> list_number;// accept list number to ass to the list
               list.appendNode(list_number); // sends number to list class
            }
            main();
            break;

         case 2:
            // Insert a node in the middle of the list.
            list.insertNode(user_input);
            main(); // this is here for me to return to my menu
            break; // this will be a break for the class

         case 3:
            // Delete the middle node.
            list.deleteNode(user_input);
            main();
            break;

         case 4:
            // Display the values in the list.
            list.displayList();
            main();
            break;

         defualt:
            cout << " INVALID ENTRY PLEASE CHOOSE NUMBERS 1-4 ";// invalid menu option message
            break;
      }

      system("pause");
      return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Why do you call `main` from `main`? What are you trying to do? You need to make loop instead of this strange solution.

Comment: I am trying to revert back to the menu options in order to choose another option.

Comment: @EasyE: That's what loops are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you recursively call `main`, you are executing another *copy* of main, with its own local variables: in particular, its own list.

You should wrap the portion of `main` that comes after the initialization (which you only want done once) in a loop (and you'll probably want a menu choice to end the program).

Comment: @ scott Hunter , Thank you , Ok I understand can you show me a quick example of how I can use a loop to wrap my menu ?  I can't seem to wrap my mind around that

Comment: `while (menu_choice != EXIT_ITEM) { ... case EXIT_ITEM: break; ... }`

Comment: @ ScottHunter .... Oh did you mean placing the whole menu in a function of its own ?

Comment: You could do it that way.

Comment: @ Scott Hunter .. You are my Over Lord You, I fixed everything Thanks a Million

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code doesn't work as expected is because your recursive call to `main()` will create a different `NumberList` object every time. Your concept of recursion is in principle OK, you just need to understand a few things:

1. **Never use `main()` as a recursive function**. This may lead to undefined behaviour and is generally considered bad coding.
2. When your program calls the same function recursively, **the variables are not the same**. You might think they are the same, but in fact they are created from scratch again, which means that you will end up with an empty `list` every time.
3. One way to do this is to define **another function** which does the same thing, and make sure you are accessing the same variables by either (i) passing them as references in the function's parameter list, or (ii) making them **static**, but this is in most cases not advised since you can easily loose track of what your function's inputs and outputs are. I would go with (i).
4. However, recursion **is not necessary here**. The correct solution is to define a `while` loop and put your `case`s in there. Use recursion only when it gives you more efficiency or performance.